# Access subclass constants after inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, constants

I have a model in my Rails application with a number of constants defined on it:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  ALIASES = {
    places: :geographic_places,
    prices: :product_prices,
    productPrices: :product_prices,
    productSpecification: :product_spec
  }

  ALIASES.each do |k, v|
    alias_attribute k, v
  end

  ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :description, :isBundle, :lastUpdate, :validFor]
  ASSOCIATIONS = [:productPrice, :productSpecification, :place]

  # The rest of the class has been omitted for brevity
end
```

My ALIASES are in a hash so I can later lookup which association I am following given an alias. You can see that I set each alias up as an `alias_attribute`.

However this snippet will be repeated in all of my models:

```
ALIASES.each do |k, v|
  alias_attribute k, v
end
```

I would like the base class, ApplicationRecord, to be able to handle that for me. I have a similar requirement for some methods in the ApplicationRecord to be aware of ATTRIBUTES and ASSOCIATIONS. However I can't find a way to access inheriting-class's constants.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  # 1
  base_class::ALIASES.each { |k, v| alias_attribute k, v } # => NameError: Uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord::ALIASES


  def class << self
    # 2
    base_class::ALIASES.each { |k, v| alias_attribute k, v } # => NameError: Uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord::ALIASES

    # 3 - inherited fires BEFORE the subclass code is run
    def inherited(subclass)
      puts subclass.name # => Product
      subclass.const_get(:ALIASES) # => NameError: uninitialized constant Product::ALIASES
    end

    # By the way, this works
    def table_name
      self.base_class.name.underscore + '_records'
    end
    # Elsewhere: Product.table_name # => 'product_records'
  end
end
```

How can I access the inheriting class's constants after they are initialized?

(Ruby 2.4.1, Rails 5.1.5)

Comment: Or alternatively I suppose, how can I fire code AFTER `inherited` is called?

Comment: Why a constant why not make a method to handle this? e.g. `def self.aliases(**args); args.each { |k,v| alias_attribute k, v }; end` and then in your models just add `aliases  places: :geographic_places,
prices: :product_prices,#...`

Comment: @engineersmnky I still need to be able to lookup the callee when given an alias. What's the proper way to save that information? Something like `@aliases[k] = v` in ApplicationRecord?

Comment: What do you mean "lookup the callee" this is an inheritance pattern. I guess if you need to store the alias names for a given method you could store them at a class level. Here is a [Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/OurFelineComputationalscience) of my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found a solution that uses aspects of both our approaches and it works very well. I'll write up a full answer soon.